# how to create a view that filters on different fields depending on the content type

Tags: views

How can I create a view that contains events and news and filters on the event date if the content is event, and the expiration date if the content is news?

I dont see where to choose both simultaneously in the filter criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to 'Filter Criteria' and hit the triangle next to 'Add'. Select 'and/or, rearange'  and you can change to OR instead of AND as well as add groups.

Comment: +1. I agree. The filter is: (content type == event AND event date OPERATOR CONDITION) OR (content type == news AND expiration date OPERATOR CONDITION)

Answer (score 0):

The business logic you are asking for is usually accomplished by 2 sql queries. You will want to use 2 `Views Attachments` or an sql `union` of 2 views results to generate the resultset you want from a visitors selected criteria. There are modules to join 2 views, or views attachments is a functionality of Views (core).

For the UI to appear as you want (a single Date selection widget) shared across the 2 Views you want to create a single [Views Global Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/global_filter) to use between these 2 Views (your site may require additional global filters, but thats up to you).

From the project page:

> Use Views Global Filter on sites that feature multiple Views. You want
>   the views to be driven by the same filter selection, for instance a
>   country, a date range, a search term or even proximity to a post code.
>   These views may be on the same page or scattered across several pages
>   on your site, however you want to offer the visitor the convenience of
>   setting the filter for all these views only once, for instance when
>   they first land on your site. Views Global Filter implements the
>   picked once, operates site-wide (POOS) principle. This means you can
>   place anywhere on your site a selection widget (drop-down, check boxes
>   etc) to globally filter all or some of your views. When the user picks
>   a value from the global selector, the value is invisibly passed as a
>   contextual filter to whatever views you like, even when these reside
>   across multiple pages. This avoids you having to duplicate filters and
>   avoids the visitor having to re-select their choice as they go from
>   page to page.